# Altering an external .js file with Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently developing a platformer video game and I want players to be able to be able to choose what skin the Player icon will use. (the file names are in square brackets [])

......

to do this I'm using an html file (which will be the gui menu were players choose their skin) [Skin Select.html]

```
<input type="button" id="Skin1" onClick="">
```

and an external .js file containing a PlayerIcon variable that is globally linked to all the levels in the game.  [Variable.js]

```
var PlayerIcon = 0; //Players Icon will change depending on what value this is
```

......

I've search this question before. But I don't understand how the methods people are providing work.
I know that you can accomplish this using jquery but I don't understand the idea behind it.

So if your answering. Would you mind also telling me exactly which attributes I will need to edit in order to make this work? Thanks ahead of time!

(I'm pretty good with JavaScript, however I don't have any experience with jQuery)

Comment: Note, `<input>` elements are self-closing.

Comment: I don't like it if another site goes around changing my js files ;)

Comment: but seriously, just store user selected skin on their own browser. For instance using cookie or localStorage.

Comment: @guest271314 oh yeah. Sorry I just put that there on instinct XP

Answer (score 0):

The file itself does not need to be altered. The value of the variable `PlayerIcon` can be set to a value selected by user.

You can use `<select>`, `<option>` elements, `change` event to set value for `PlayerIcon` variable.

```js
let PlayerIcon = 0;

document.querySelector("select").onchange = function() {
  PlayerIcon = Number(this.value);
  console.log(PlayerIcon);
}
```

```html
<select name="skin">
  <option>select a skin</option>
  <option value="1">skin 1</option>
  <option value="2">skin 2</option>
  <option value="3">skin 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: ok is the top code section for the .js file and the bottom one for the html

Comment: Yes. `let PlayerIcon = 0` is to demonstrate global variable being set and re-assigned a different value. Load the file where `PlayerIcon` is defined before file where `change` event handler is defined. You should be able to try the process at plnkr https://plnkr.co, where files can be created and referenced at left panel.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. This is what I did.
I put the entire javascript code in the .js folder (including the function) and  I but the html in the other folder (I called in the js file using <script src=""> before creating the <select> element)

Comment: _"It doesn't seem to be working."_ Can you create a plnkr https://plnkr.co to demonstrate? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ok here you go: https://plnkr.co/edit/zXvXJbaWsqyTA6fGIFN8?p=preview
The extra <p> and <script> element in the html file is just so that I could view the PlayerIcon

Comment: `script.js` is loaded before `<select>` is defined. Use `load` event of `window` where `<script>` is loaded before elements have been defined. See https://plnkr.co/edit/Htbfs5Afc2VuQrtotAHX?p=preview